# Unable to resolve jitpack.io dependencies

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to integrate [PrismView](https://github.com/ppamorim/PrismView) lib in my project. I have include jitpack.io in project build.gradle, Below are the code snippet.

```
buildscript {
   repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
}
```

And include dependencies in project module as follow:

```
dependencies {
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
   compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
   compile 'com.github.ppamorim:PrismView:0.3'
}
```

But on syncing it is giving following error:

```
Error:(24, 13) Failed to resolve: com.github.ppamorim:PrismView:0.3
```

Any lead to resolve this will be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.ppamorim:prismview:0.3'
}
```

Should be just a simple typo.

Comment: Thanks, It works. But I am still not able to use it's functionalities :( Any help???

Answer (score 1):

Use it with lowercase : https://github.com/ppamorim/PrismView

```
repositories {
  maven {
    url "https://jitpack.io"
  }
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.github.ppamorim:prismview:0.3'
}
```

Here is yours and look at your mistake/typo whatever:

> compile 'com.github.ppamorim:**P**rismView:0.3'

Comment: Thanks, It works. But I am still not able to use it's functionalities :( Any help???

Comment: Let's see the codes and look what did you do so far by creating an another question.Also, there is a sample always:https://github.com/ppamorim/PrismView/tree/master/sample